# control array, links by role in header, laravel-admin

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-admin

I use https://laravel-admin.org/docs/en/README on my site.

I have a general header in the admin panel, which displays all the sections that can be edited, here is the code:

```
<?php foreach(Admin::menuLinks() as $link) { ?>
<?php if (in_array($link['uri'], ['users', 'posts', 'comments'])) {?> 
    <a class="sidebar-toggle sidebar-toggle-link" role="button" href="<?= admin_url($link['uri']) ?>"><i class="fa <?= $link['icon'] ?>"></i>
        <?= admin_trans ($link['title']) ?>
    </a>
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

So, I have 3 partitions. Each section will have its own admin, who will have a corresponding role. Now all admins with roles see all links in the header, but I need to hide them and make sure that the admin sees only the link to which he has a role with rights. How can I do such a check in the header? To display these links depending on the user's role.

I did it this way:

```
<?php foreach(Admin::menuLinks() as $link) { ?>
<?php if (Admin::user()->isRole('administrator')) {?>
<?php if (in_array($link['uri'], ['users', 'posts', 'comments'])) {?> 
    <a class="sidebar-toggle sidebar-toggle-link" role="button" href="<?= admin_url($link['uri']) ?>"><i class="fa <?= $link['icon'] ?>"></i>
        <?= admin_trans ($link['title']) ?>
    </a>
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>

<?php if (Admin::user()->isRole('post-admin')) {?>
<?php if (in_array($link['uri'], ['posts'])) {?> 
    <a class="sidebar-toggle sidebar-toggle-link" role="button" href="<?= admin_url($link['uri']) ?>"><i class="fa <?= $link['icon'] ?>"></i>
        <?= admin_trans ($link['title']) ?>
    </a>
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>

<?php if (Admin::user()->isRole('comment-admin')) {?>
<?php if (in_array($link['uri'], ['comments'])) {?> 
    <a class="sidebar-toggle sidebar-toggle-link" role="button" href="<?= admin_url($link['uri']) ?>"><i class="fa <?= $link['icon'] ?>"></i>
        <?= admin_trans ($link['title']) ?>
    </a>
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

It works, but I ended up with too much repetitive code. Is it possible to do it somehow simpler, to control all the roles in the array?

Something like this:

```
<?php foreach(Admin::menuLinks() as $link) { ?>
<?php if (in_array($link['uri'], 
     if (Admin::user()->isRole('administrator')) {
          ['users', 'posts', 'comments']
     }

    else if (Admin::user()->isRole('post-admin')) {
          ['posts']
     }
)) {?> 
    <a class="sidebar-toggle sidebar-toggle-link" role="button" href="<?= admin_url($link['uri']) ?>"><i class="fa <?= $link['icon'] ?>"></i>
        <?= admin_trans ($link['title']) ?>
    </a>
<?php } ?>
```

Or:

```
<?php if (in_array($link['uri'], 
Admin::user()->isRole('administrator') ? ['users', 'posts', 'comments'] : 
Admin::user()->isRole('post-admin') ? ['posts'] : '')) {?>
```

But both options don't work for me..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have multiple possible solution. One would be to make a helper `adminHasAccess($link['uri'])` and use it elegantly in your blade.

```
function adminHasAccess($uri)
{
    switch($uri) {
        case 'users':
            return Admin::user()->isRole('administrator');
        case 'posts':
            return Admin::user()->isOne(['post-admin', 'administrator']);
        case 'comments':
            return Admin::user()->isOne(['comment-admin', 'administrator']);
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
```

And in your blade:

```
<?php foreach(Admin::menuLinks() as $link) { ?>
    <?php if (adminHasAccess($link['uri'])) {?> 
        <a class="sidebar-toggle sidebar-toggle-link" role="button" href="<?= admin_url($link['uri']) ?>"><i class="fa <?= $link['icon'] ?>"></i>
            <?= admin_trans ($link['title']) ?>
        </a>
    <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

For the jammed solution, you can try

```
<?php foreach(Admin::menuLinks() as $link) { ?>
    <?php if (
        (Admin::user()->isRole('administrator') &&  in_array($link['uri'], ['users', 'posts', 'comments'])) ||
        (Admin::user()->isRole('post-admin') && in_array($link['uri'], ['posts'])) ||
        (Admin::user()->isRole('comment-admin') && in_array($link['uri'], ['comments']))
        ) {?>

        <a class="sidebar-toggle sidebar-toggle-link" role="button" href="<?= admin_url($link['uri']) ?>"><i class="fa <?= $link['icon'] ?>"></i>
            <?= admin_trans ($link['title']) ?>
        </a>

    <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Or more compact but less maintainable

```
<?php foreach(Admin::menuLinks() as $link) { ?>
    <?php if (in_array($link['uri'], Admin::user()->isRole('administrator') ? ['users', 'posts', 'comments'] : (Admin::user()->isRole('post-admin') ? ['posts'] : (Admin::user()->isRole('comment-admin') ? ['comments'] : [])))) {?>

        <a class="sidebar-toggle sidebar-toggle-link" role="button" href="<?= admin_url($link['uri']) ?>"><i class="fa <?= $link['icon'] ?>"></i>
            <?= admin_trans ($link['title']) ?>
        </a>

    <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a tipical situation where Policies should help to resolve your problem

I would create a Policies for User, Post, Comment Models and later in my view I would use **can()** and **cannot()** helpers to check view on models with the auth user, as in your policies you are checking the auth user Rol.

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authorization#writing-policies